# vectorizing a nested loop where one loop variable depends on the other

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vectorization, multidimensional-array

I've recently learned how to vectorize a "simple" nested  loop in a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152610/vectorizing-ther-higher-dimensions-in-nested-for-loop-in-matlab) I've asked. However, now I'm trying also to vectorize the following loop

```
A=rand(80,80,10,6,8,8);

I=rand(size(A1,3),1);
C=rand(size(A1,4),1);
B=rand(size(A1,5),1);

for i=1:numel(I)
    for v=1:numel(C)
        for j=1:numel(B)
            for k=1:j
                A(:,:,i,v,j,k)= A(:,:,i,v,j,k)*I(i)*C(v)*B(j)*((k-1>0)+1);               
            end
        end
    end
end
```

So now `k` depends in `j`...  What have I tried so far:
The combination of `j` and `k` terms (i.e. `B(j)*((k-1>0)+1)` gives a triangular matrix that I manage to vectorize independently:

```
  B2=tril([ones(8,1)*B']');
  B2(2:end,2:end)=2*B2(2:end,2:end);
```

But that gives me the (j,k) matrix properly and not a way to use it to vectorize the remaining loop. Maybe I'm in the wrong path too...  So how can I vectorize that type of loop?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In [one of your comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152610/vectorizing-ther-higher-dimensions-in-nested-for-loop-in-matlab#comment41032797_26152799) to the accepted solution of the previous question, you mentioned that successive `bsxfun(@times,..,permute..)` based codes were faster. If that's the case, you can use a similar approach here as well. Here's the code that uses such a pattern alongwith `tril` -

```
B1 = tril(bsxfun(@times,B,[1 ones(1,numel(B)-1).*2]));
v1 = bsxfun(@times,B1, permute(C,[3 2 1]));
v2 = bsxfun(@times,v1, permute(I,[4 3 2 1]));
A = bsxfun(@times,A, permute(v2,[5 6 4 3 1 2]));
```

Comment: wonderful! it's much more elegant and runs 25% faster than @natan's solution.

Comment: @Max Awesome! Good to know that too!

Comment: This solution reminds me of [Ramanujan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srinivasa_Ramanujan).  I have absolutely no idea how in hell you came up with that answer.

Answer (score 2):

You were close. The vectorization you proposed indeed follows the (j,k) logic, but doing `tril` adds zeros in places where the loop doesn't go into. Using the solution for your previous question (@david's) is not complete as it multiplies all elements including these zero value elements that the loop doesn't go into. My solution to that, is to find these zero elements and replace them with 1 (so simple):

Starting with your code:

```
B2=tril([ones(8,1)*B']');
B2(2:end,2:end)=2*B2(2:end,2:end);
```

and following the vectorization shown in the previous question:

```
s=size(A);
[b,c,d]=ndgrid(I,C,B2);
F=b.*c.*d;
F(F==0)=1; % this is the step that is important for your case.
A=reshape(A,s(1),s(2),[]);
A=bsxfun(@times,A,permute(F(:),[3 2 1]));
A=reshape(A,s);
```

For the size of `A` used in the question this cuts about 50% of the run time, not bad...