# MATLAB : 3 dimensional matrix with multipication with a vector

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I have  `A` matrix which is `16x16x155460`. I have a  `B` vector which is `12955x1`. I want to multiply each `1:16x1:16x1+12*n:12+12*n`with the elements of `B(n)`. So my goal is to find the weighted sum of the `A` according to `B`. My way to do this as follows (`I don't want to use for-loop` and my method gives wrong answer, I could not obtain the 1:12 vectors which is consecutive) :

```
B = repmat(B,[1 16 16]);
B = permute(B,[2 3 1]);
B = repmat(B,[1 1 12]);
result = B.*(A);
```

As a small example `n=2` :

```
A(:,:,1)=[1 2; 3 4]
A(:,:,2)=[1 2; 3 4]
A(:,:,3)=[1 2; 3 4]
A(:,:,4)=[1 2; 3 4]
B      = [2,3]
```

Result would be:

```
result(:,:,1)=A(:,:,1)*B(1);
result(:,:,2)=A(:,:,2)*B(1);
result(:,:,3)=A(:,:,1)*B(2);
result(:,:,4)=A(:,:,2)*B(2);
```

Comment: What would be the output array size?

Comment: I would reshape the matrix to `16x16x12x12955` first...

Comment: Do I understand you right, that you use only `A(16,16,:)` and non of the other data in A? Your formula `1+12*n:12+12*n` is wrong, it does not start with 0 and exceeds the length of A

Comment: That example just confused me :(

Comment: Pitfalls of over-simplified examples really @beaker

Comment: @Divakar But it doesn't even use all of the planes of `A`

Comment: @beaker Yup, that's another issue here.

Comment: And are the elements of `B` repeated individually like `1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2` or as a vector like `1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2`? (assuming `B = [1 2]`)

Comment: Think about dividing the 16x16x12955 matrix to new matrix which has 12 pages
1:16x1:16x1:12 (All of this values would be multiplied by first element of the vector)
1:16x1:16x13:23 (All of this values would be multiplied by second element of the vector)
and goes like this. 
So we have 12 images which are 16x16 and they would be multiplied by a constant for considering weighted mean.
I'm sorry to get confused you :(

Comment: .. and the output array size would be ...?

Comment: 16x16x155460 is true value and the result would be 16x16x155460 matrix  again the only difference would be multipication with vector values. In the comment I wrote wrong number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood the problem correctly, you can use the powerful trio of `bsxfun`, `permute` and `reshape` to solve it, like so -

```
[M,N,R] = size(A);
mult_out = bsxfun(@times,reshape(A,M,N,numel(B),[]),permute(B(:),[4 3 1 2]))
out = reshape(mult_out,M,N,[])
```

Comment: why are you using permute for B, it is a vector?

Comment: @toygankılıç permute on `B` just "shifts" all its elements to the third dimension, which is what you want for expanded elementwise multiplication with `A`.  Read more about how permute works , here - http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efficient solutions! I know it is stupid question but matrix dimensions could be problem sometimes. Is there a difference between [4 3 1 2] and [3 4 1 2]?

Comment: @toygankılıç Nope, both would be the same. As long as you keep `1` at the third position, dimension IDs at other three places don't matter at all.

Comment: How could you feel which dimension will be important for multipication?

Comment: @toygankılıç Not sure what you mean by "important". But, let's say you meant for this particular problem, which dimension is "required" instead of "important" for multiplication, that would be third dim in this case, as third dim of `A` elements are to be multiplied by `B`. If by "important", instead you meant which dimensions are to be used at places other than the third dimension, that's purely random, but I like to go from higher to lower. See [`here`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26187897/3293881) for a related higher dimensional permute example.